# Why would a python library run from the desktop, but not when called from PHP?

Tags: python, php, json, libraries

I have written a web app that calls python code in places to retrieve and store information. It worked fine until today when I had reason to install the jsonpickle library. The library does precisely what's expected when the python code is run from shell (it converts nested structures to JSON; the data in this case is too complex for json.dumps(), which I would otherwise use). But when called from php, it fails to load. I've never seen this with any other library.

Extremely simplified code below:

Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import datetime
import jsonpickle

nowS = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")
nowJ = jsonpickle.encode({"now": nowS})
print(nowJ)
```

The above works just fine whether I have it print `nowS` or `nowJ`.

However when the same code it called from PHP, it fails.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
   $json = shell_exec('python3 /var/www/py/trivial.py');
   $json = trim($json);
   echo "<p>json: " . addslashes($json) . "</p>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

It can be made to work if I print `nowS` and comment out all references to `jsonpickle`. The line `import jsonpickle` prevents PHP from being able execute this code even if jsonpickle is never later invoked.

The datetime and other libraries, installed earlier, cause no similar problem.

I'm confounded. What am I missing here?

---

Addendum, November 15.

None of the excellent selections below worked. I gave up and installed the jsonpickle library with `sudo pip3` instead of `pip3`, and that seems to have solved it.

Comment: Due to PATH differences, it could be that PHP is running a different "python3" than you are running in the terminal.  Unlike datetime, jsonpickle is not a default python module - it needs to be installed with `pip install jsonpickle` and be available on the "python path" in order to be imported. Run `which python3` to get the full path, then use that full path in  the PHP like shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/python3 /var/www/py/trivial.py').
You can also wrap the `import jsonpickle` in a try statement and print out debug info like sys.path if the import fails.

Answer (score 1):

A more robust method would be to use a virtual environment.

You can do this in bash

```
python3 -m venv /var/www/py/venv
source /var/www/py/venv/bin/activate && pip install jsonpickle
```

Then in PHP you can do

```
$json = shell_exec('source /var/www/py/venv/bin/activate && python3 /var/www/py/trivial.py');
```

Comment: strftime is just used in the trivial demo code. The actual data comes from a third party API and is not compatible with json.dumps(). And since it comes from a third party, I have no ability to modify it at source.

Comment: tried the above; if `import jsonpickle` appears in the source code, the python won't run even if jsonpickle is never used. Absent jsonpickle, it works. Sadly. I need jsonpickle.

Comment: changed to virtual environment method, maybe this will work for you

Answer (score 0):

It must use full path. Like this:

```
shell_exec('/usr/bin/python3 /var/www/py/trivial.py');
```

Or try to create a venv (virtual environment) and install all required packages.

```
shell_exec('/var/www/py/venv/bin/python3 /var/www/py/trivial.py');
```

FYI: If you use apache to host your php, you also need to check the user (such as www-data) permissions.

Comment: As with the other approaches I have tried, the above works fine until `import jsonpickle` appears at the top of the python code. If it's there. the code works fine in the shell but fails in PHP.